# In Windows, Node.js' path.join() prepends the current working directory's drive letter(C:\) automatically

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm using Node.js' `path.join()` to generate the path in Windows.

```
const path = require('path');
const myDestPath = path.join('/D', 'test.txt');  // D drive
```

This results in `C:\D\test.txt`, prepending the current working directory's drive letter (`C:\`) automatically, which is not what I want.

How do I go about setting the different drive letter other than `C:\` in Node.js?

I've tried `path.resolve()` as well, but got the same result.

Comment: try to use __dirname, instead of hard coding absolute path

Comment: @r7r Can't use __dirname because the path I'm generating is the destination that I will move files to.

Comment: tried to add one of the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add extra slash to create path

```
const path = require('path');
const myDestPath = path.join('D:\\', 'test.txt');  // D drive
console.log(myDestPath)
```

results in `D:\test.txt`